# How can i find rows that has null value according to ID in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, csv

I have following data & i want to find only Id where rest of all column has null values with the help of pandas, How can i take only Id which has all column is null.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use if `Id` is column use [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) with remove `Id` column and test if all values are `True`s by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html), last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
id1 = df.loc[df.drop('Id', axis=1).isna().all(axis=1), 'Id'].tolist()

#if need omit first column for test
id1 = df.loc[df.iloc[:, 1:].isna().all(axis=1), 'Id'].tolist()
```

If `Id` is `index` use:

```
id1 = df1.index[df1.isna().all(axis=1)].tolist()
```

Comment: With the solution which you gave me. I got the id where null value now how can i drop that row from dataframe??

Comment: @DipamSoni - Is `Id` index of column?

Comment: yes the Id is index of the column

Comment: @DipamSoni - So need `df.dropna(how='all')` ?